# My external hard drive won't format no matter what I use

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a WD hard drive and it was extremely slow even though the drivers were fully updated , it first showed up as a local disk then I had to click it then after 10 minutes of loading the hard drive finally shows up and every action I do on the hard drive takes 10-20 minutes to respond. I finally formatted it using disk manager but then it became RAW and now I cant format it again or use cmd to fix it. 
I've use EaseUS, cmd,disk management and file explorer all on Windows 10 to try and fix it.

Comment: Are you able to read any SMART data out of it using something like Speccy? Sounds like it might be on the way out.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like the drive is defective.  If ita new, I would suggest returning/replacing it to the store you purchased it from.

If you are unable to exchange it at the place of purchase, you could call Western Digital for support.  They also might replace it if it is under warranty.

If it is out of warranty and non-returnable, you could open the enclosure up, remove the hard drive, and hook it directly up to your computer.  This would allow you to try and format it directly and see if the problem is the with the drive itself, or with the USB to SATA electronics.  However, from your description, the drive itself sounds defective.